# how to create a subquery in sql using count based on outer query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I hope someone can help me with this query. Basically I have two queries that I want to "combine". I want the second query as an extra column along with the first query.
The first one is this :

```
SELECT t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr, 
t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code, 
Count(t_Load.Load_Id) AS CurrentLoadCount,
t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr

FROM t_Load INNER JOIN (t_Storage_Location INNER JOIN t_Item_Storage_Location ON 
t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) ON 
(t_Load.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) 
AND (t_Load.MMM_Id_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.MMM_Id_Nbr)


where ((((t_Item_Storage_Location.MMM_Id_Nbr) Between '702004%' And '702011%') 
AND ((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%A') 
AND ((t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code)='CD') 
AND ((t_Load.Active_Status_Ind)='A') 
AND ((t_Load.QC_Status_Code) Like 'R%') 
AND ((t_Load.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%B'))
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%C')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%D')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%E'))

)
GROUP BY t_Item_Storage_Location.MMM_Id_Nbr,
t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr, 
t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code,
t_Load.MMM_Facility_Code,
t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr

HAVING
Count(t_Load.Load_Id)<4
```

The second one, is based on the t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr of the first one. Basically I want a count of all the loads with that mmm_id_nbr.

```
SELECT count(Load_ID) as LoadCount, MMM_Id_Nbr, storage_Loc_Nbr
FROM t_load 
WHERE QC_Status_Code like 'R%' and mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' and Active_Status_Ind='A'
GROUP by MMM_Id_Nbr, storage_loc_Nbr
```

Answer (score 0):

take this more as an advice than help, the query is too unoptimized, maybe you should rethink your database structure

Answer (score 0):

Well I can answer your question

You can join to another query with something like this

```
Select KeyColumn,Column1 From Table1
left Join ( Select ForeignKeyColumn, Count(*) From Table2 Group By ForeignKeyColumn) dummyTableName
On Table1.KeyColumn = dummyTableName.ForeignKeyColumn
```

I was going to figure out exactly how to apply this technique to your query, but my fingers mutinied.

A quick tip

```
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%B'))
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%C')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%D')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%E'))
```

could be replaced with

```
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%[BCDE]'))
```

for instance

Comment: hi, using %[ABCDE] did not result in the same number of records as the way I did.

Comment: @user1754716 It didn't? Weird should be any storage_loc_nbr ending in A,B,C,D,E. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I did a subquery like this now:

```
Select b.Storage_Loc_Nbr, b.CurrentLoadCount,
(SELECT count(Load_ID) as LoadCount 
FROM t_load c
WHERE b.MMM_Id_Nbr=c.MMM_Id_Nbr

)as CountOtherLoc

FROM
(

SELECT * FROM

(

SELECT t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr, 
t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code, 
Count(t_Load.Load_Id) AS CurrentLoadCount,
t_load.MMM_Id_Nbr

FROM t_Load INNER JOIN (t_Storage_Location INNER JOIN t_Item_Storage_Location ON 
t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) ON 
(t_Load.Storage_Loc_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) AND      (t_Load.MMM_Id_Nbr = t_Item_Storage_Location.MMM_Id_Nbr)


where ((((t_Item_Storage_Location.MMM_Id_Nbr) Between '702004%' And '702011%') 
AND ((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%A') 
AND ((t_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Type_Code)='CD') 
AND ((t_Load.Active_Status_Ind)='A') 
AND ((t_Load.QC_Status_Code) Like 'R%') 
AND ((t_Load.MMM_Facility_Code)='MC')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%B'))
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%C')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%D')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%E'))

 ...

as a

)  
as b
```

it is giving me what I want EXCEPT the countOtherLoc column does not have the where conditions I had and i can't use multiple in this type of subquery.
I need to add the "WHERE QC_Status_Code like 'R%' and mmm_Facility_Code ='MC' and Active_Status_Ind='A' under the line 4 but it wont let me. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

are you have some mistakes in query? Why use some OR and than after AND on LIKE query. A query is totaly moron.

Let's considere this such as LIKE query:

```
where [...]
AND ((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%A') 

[....]

# what about above on %A ?
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%B'))
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%C')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%D')) 
OR (((t_Item_Storage_Location.Storage_Loc_Nbr) Like '%E'))
```

You want search exactly string ending with A `%A` but is nothing importing about others queries search in OR clause? This is not good query and is not correctly setted.

`GROUP BY` can spawn your server for too many results. Are you killer?

If you want use Like you should use REGEXP instead Like for too many options. You missed some fundamentals of properly SQL optimizations.

Comment: That was a bit strong wasn't it? Oh and SQL 2008 only supports Regular Expressions via CLR, and you'd want to have a deep think before going down that route.

Comment: the reason I use OR is because i want a list of all storage location numbers that ends in A, B, C, D, E. and Or is the way to do it.